# How to solve Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined in vue?

Tags: vue.js

I am setting default headers in my vue application, but when I load the app it show me error.

> main.js?56d7:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined

[image]

**Code**

```
const token = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
if (token) {
  Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.header.common["Authorization"] = token;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a working codepen based on your issue.
In your case, you need to create axios client.
Please check this codepen. https://codepen.io/plsdev89/pen/VwaPGzr

```
let apiClient = axios.create({
   baseURL: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com",
   headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   }
})

const token = "testtoken";
if (token) {
   apiClient.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = token;  
}

Vue.prototype.$http = apiClient;
```

Comment: Thanku @endmaster0809 for this work,  you save my day